# omitting final comma in JSTL <c:out>

Tags: java, jsp, jstl

I reviewed previous examples on this site and I couldn't get anything to work.  I also googled my dilemma but had no success.

I'm trying to debug some code here.  I can seem to drop the last comma.  Thoughts?

```
<c:forEach items="${userDeptList}" var="userDeptVar" varStatus="userDeptCounter" >
   <c:if test="${contactsVar.userId==userDeptVar.userID}">
      <c:forEach items="${deptPtypeList}" var="deptsVar" varStatus="deptsCounter" > 
         <c:if test="${deptsVar.ptypeID==userDeptVar.deptID}">
            <c:out value="${deptsVar.type}" escapeXml="false"></c:out>
            <c:out value="," escapeXml="false"></c:out> 
         </c:if>    
      </c:forEach>                          
   </c:if>                  
</c:forEach>
```

Comment: What are you trying to do it here? input? output? what examples you read?

Comment: i'm still getting a comma after the last department

Answer (score 1):

To omit the final comma you can test if you are on the last item in this way

```
<c:forEach items="${userDeptList}" var="userDeptVar" varStatus="userDeptCounter" >
   <c:if test="${contactsVar.userId==userDeptVar.userID}">
      <c:forEach items="${deptPtypeList}" var="deptsVar" varStatus="deptsCounter" > 
         <c:if test="${deptsVar.ptypeID==userDeptVar.deptID}">
            <c:out value="${deptsVar.type}" escapeXml="false"></c:out>
            <c:if test="${not userDeptCounter.last}>
              <c:out value="," escapeXml="false"></c:out> 
            </c:if>
         </c:if>    
      </c:forEach>                          
   </c:if>                  
</c:forEach>
```

Here a list of all *varStatus* properties

```
current    The item (from the collection) for the current round of iteration
index      The zero-based index for the current round of iteration
count      The one-based count for the current round of iteration
first      Flag indicating whether the current round is the first pass through the iteration
last       Flag indicating whether the current round is the last pass through the iteration
begin      The value of the begin attribute
end        The value of the end attribute
step       The value of the step attribute
```

Answer (score 0):

use `varStatus`

```
<c:if test="${not deptsCounter.last}">
</c:if>
```

Comment: i'm still getting a comma after the last department

Comment: updated, the inner most loop's varstatus needs to be considered

Comment: i'm at a loss....this should work <c:if test="${not deptsCounter.last}">
</c:if>
I tried it before i posted. I dont get it.